# Android Studio Instalation Issues

Tags: java

I am installing and configuring Android Studio and Flutter to work in VS Code, but I get this error when doing `flutter -doctor`. I have tried everything I researched in many places, but the error persists.

Could someone give me some help? I would appreciate it a lot.

```
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to determine Android Studio version.
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
```

I mainly tried installing different versions of Android Studio, flutter, and even Java and nothing